# How to disable all autocorrect in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am frustrated because the Outlook makes some rather rude and arrogant autocorrections and does so repeatedly even after I go back and undo them.  I tried many things to disable the feature, such as turn off `Edit -> Substitutions -> Text Replacement` as well as all `Edit -> Spelling and Grammar` options.  But it still does it and it makes it downright impossible to override.  Is there any way this can be done or is it one of those Microsoft things?

Comment: This question does not seem well researched

Comment: I did research it but none of the search results solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

### Turn on or off AutoCorrect options

1. From the main **Microsoft Outlook** window, Click **File**
2. From the **Outlook Options** window click **Mail**
3. Click the **Spelling and AutoCorrect** button
4. From the **Editor Options** window click the **Autocorrect Options** button

[Search Phrase](https://www.google.com/#fp=9a4d4d8cb94d2d27&q=disable+autocorrect+outlook+2010)

***I have verified these directions works with all recent versions of Outlook.***

Comment: I don't have `Tools --> Options` in 14.3

Comment: The last step here is to remove the tick from "Replace text as you type".

Answer (score 0):

File -> Outlook Preferences-> AutoCorrect -> Exceptions -> First Letter -> add ' (apostrophe) symbol so it won't automatically make the next letter in a contraction in caps.